# boolean variable as template parameter input

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use variables set with the `Variables`-Screen in Azure Pipelines as the input for a template parameter, but get the error:

> Encountered error(s) while parsing pipeline YAML:
> /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 18, Col: 25): The 'androidIsLibrary' parameter value '$(ANDROID_IS_LIBRARY)' is not a valid Boolean.

I built a template within Azure Pipelines. The template takes several Parameters. On of it looks like this:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: androidIsLibrary
    type: boolean
    default: false
```

I have set a variable inside a variable group `ANDROID_IS_LIBRARY` with value `false`.

I added the variable group inside my pipeline with the following statement:

```yaml
variables:
  - group: adr-general-library
```

After that I included my template with parameter as shown here:

```yaml
jobs:
  - template: job--android--build_and_deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      androidIsLibrary: $(ANDROID_IS_LIBRARY)
```

I can't find an example for this particular use case in the Azure DevOps documentation, so I hope somebody already faced that problem. I want to use that template with parameters but want to structure my parameters centralized in a variable group. There are a lot more variables and parameters, so it is not a solution to just put the variable definition directly into the templates. And I am also not able to change the template.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have encountered the exact same issue before.

The root cause of this issue is that the variable in variable group is string type instead of the boolean type.

So when you pass the variable value to parameter, it will show the error message.

I confirmed this issue with our product group and this is by design.

This is the reply:

> at the point where we're processing ${{ templates }}, the contents of $(variables) are not processed. So indeed, "$(BooleanVar)" will never be a boolean. In fact, no variable can ever be a boolean - variables are always strings. This is working as designed.

For a workaround, you need to change the parameter type as **string** type in Template:

For example:

```
parameters:
  - name: androidIsLibrary
    type: string
    default: false
```

Then it will work.

Another method is that you could define the variable in the Main Yaml file and use this format `${{variables.variablename}}`

For example:

```
variables:
  - name: one
    value: true

steps:
  - template: build.yml
    parameters:
      androidIsLibrary: ${{ variables.one }}
```

Comment: aint working for me.

Comment: @TheFool, was you able to solve it? The `$(`, `${{` and `$[` do not work for me. All these three approaches pass a string instead of a boolean.

Comment: @manymanymore, not I dont think so. I probably have used a condition in the template.

Answer (score 5):

##### This happens because *template expansion* is done before *variable expansion* ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline)). Variable references like `$(Foo)` are not yet processed when the template parameter type is validated.

The first step in pipeline processing is only about replacing all `template: xxx` references in the YAML tree with the target YAML elements, and handling template *parameters* and any encountered template (compile-time) expressions, which look like `${{ ... }}`.

---

The error message which goes like
      “`The 'someVar' parameter value '$(SOME_VAR)' is not a valid Boolean.`”
**does not mean that the *content* of the variable** `SOME_VAR` **is wrong** (not `true` or `false`).

It means that **the literal text** `$(SOME_VAR)`, i.e. including the dollar sign, the parentheses and the variable *name*, **is not a valid boolean value.** Because that's all the parser sees at the time it is doing this early *template expansion*.

If the type of the template parameter was changed to a `string`, it would naturally accept even the value of `$(SOME_VAR)`. But an expression like `${{ parameters.someVar }}` encountered later inside the template would not be replaced with a `True` or `False`, as one might expect.

It would rather be replaced again just with the literal text `$(SOME_VAR)`, as it is. And only later, when actually running the relevant step or doing other evaluation, it might get replaced with the real *value* the variable has at the moment (that is, if these variable expansions are allowed in the given context at all).

(On the other hand, it is superfluous to reference `boolean` template *parameters* in constructs formatted like e.g. `condition: eq(${{ parameters.someVar }}, 'true')`. The inner expression will already only ever expand to the real `true` or `false` value, so just `condition: ${{ parameters.someVar }}` is enough.)

---

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) specify that only "*parameters* and *statically defined variables*" can be accessed from the compile-time template expressions in format `${{ ... }}` . This means that even if there is a syntax which allows referencing variables like `variables.Foo` or `variables['Foo']`, it does not work for all of them at this time.

The list of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) has a dedicated column "Available in templates?", which shows whether it is possible to use each of them during the early template expressions evaluation or not.

What "statically defined" means with user-defined variables, the variable must be set in the `variables` section of the YAML file. Providing it only in the pipeline definition or only when starting the build in the ADO UI would not work (it would expand to an empty string). But variables set statically in the YAML file cannot be set (overridden) from the UI at all, which is quite limiting...

---

#### My suggestion is to use `parameters` instead of `variables`

**at least for values that are supposed to be changed by users sometimes.**

They are much better than variables for this purpose, allowing one to prepare a nice UI with properly labeled text boxes, checkboxes, radio buttons etc., instead of the poor string-only variables experience:

[image: Screenshot of YAML pipeline parameters UI]

And well, most importantly, **they work when passed as parameters further to templates.**

But yes, they are not a replacement for things like variable groups. Changing the inner template might be needed then, to reference relevant variables directly, or take `string` parameters instead of typed `boolean` etc. after all.

Answer (score 2):

Not ideal but this should work:

```
jobs:
  - template: job--android--build_and_deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      ${{ if eq(variables['ANDROID_IS_LIBRARY'], 'true') }}:
        androidIsLibrary: true
      differentParam: 'someText'
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the boolean; it worked for me:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: use_oauth2
  displayName: oauth2 Authentication
  type: boolean
  default: false
  values:
  - true
  - false
```

Answer (score -1):

When you pass parameter to template you need to use ${{ parameters.xyz }} syntax