# Pipeline variable is not getting evaluated correctly

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have defined a Pipeline variable using the UI interface for my pipeline:
[image]

And I am consuming that variable in my pipeline `azure-pipelines.yml`:

```
name: MyRepo.Deployment.$(date:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)
...
jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
...
      - template: azure-pipelines.yml@Common-YAML
        parameters:
          ...
          enable_datasync_job: ${{ eq(variables.enable_datasync_job, 'true') }}
```

That variable then gets passed to a template that expects a `boolean`.
The issue is that when I run the pipeline and the `azure-pipelines.yml@Common-YAML` template gets expanded, the value of `enable_datasync_job` is always `False`

What am I missing here? Is it because both my pipeline and the template share the same variable/parameter name?

Comment: Are you trying to override the value of `enable_datasync_job` to `true` using this expression `${{ eq(variables.enable_datasync_job, 'true') }}`

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that `enable_datasync_job` is defined in the UI as `false`

**Option 1**

To override the above variable that is defined in the UI, you can add this [bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash) to your pipeline

```
- bash: |
    echo $(ENABLE_DATASYNC_JOB) # outputs as false
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=enable_datasync_job;]true" # override
- bash: |
    echo $(ENABLE_DATASYNC_JOB) # outputs as true
```

Since your template accepts the parameter of type boolean, you would have something like the below

```
# template.yml
parameters:
- name: enable_datasync_job
  type: boolean

steps:
- bash: |
    echo $(ENABLE_DATASYNC_JOB)
```

And your main yml file

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=enable_datasync_job;]true" # override
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      enable_datasync_job: $(enable_datasync_job) # fail
```

But the above `azure-pipelines.yml` will fail because of typecasting of string into boolean. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65121581/boolean-variable-as-template-parameter-input) for more details

> /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 11, Col: 28): The 'enable_datasync_job'
> parameter value '$(enable_datasync_job)' is not a valid Boolean.

According to the above post, you can change the data type of parameter to string in your `template.yml`

```
parameters:
- name: enable_datasync_job
  type: string
```

**Final result of option 1**

```
# template.yml
parameters:
- name: enable_datasync_job
  type: string

steps:
- bash: |
    echo $(ENABLE_DATASYNC_JOB) #outputs true
```

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=enable_datasync_job;]true" # override
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      enable_datasync_job: $(enable_datasync_job)
```

**Option 2**

If you are looking to just pass the value `true` to your template without overriding the pipeline variable, you can reference the value that you passed like this

```
# template.yml
parameters:
- name: enable_datasync_job
  type: boolean

steps:
- bash: |
    echo ${{ parameters.enable_datasync_job }} # outputs true
    echo $(ENABLE_DATASYNC_JOB) # outputs false
```

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
steps:
  - template: template.yml
    parameters:
      enable_datasync_job: true
```

The reason why it was returning `False` for you is because you have used this expression while passing value to the parameter

```
${{ eq(variables.enable_datasync_job, 'true') }}
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#eq), the `eq` function

> Evaluates True if parameters are equal

You tried to evaluate if the UI variable was equal to true instead of setting it

**The expression that you used above will always return `False` because false(UI variable value) is not equal to true(set in the expression)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! It does help! I have a couple of questions. 1. Isn't that expression `${{ eq(variables.enable_datasync_job, 'true') }}` return a `boolean`? That was my assumption. I thought that way it would set the my templates's `enable_datasync_job` to true or false depending on what value I set in the pipeline variable's UI.

2. If I were to make the above work, what changes I need to make?